# undefined is not an object (evaluating 'Context._context') - React Native

Tags: react-native, expo, react-context

I am trying to wrap one of my navigators with User Context that I created. I have achieved this before in other projects but I am encountering an issue. I Tried following [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58228046/context-api-using-usecontext-in-react-native-is-showing-a-typeerror) but it doesn't seem to be the same issue I am encountering. I can't exactly tell what is wrong here.

**App.js Code :**

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect } from "react";
import { View, Text, AsyncStorage, Button } from "react-native";
import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";
import HomeScreen from "./src/screens/HomeScreen";
import LoginScreen from "./src/screens/login";
import CalendarScreen from "./src/screens/Calendar";
import SignUpScreen from "./src/screens/signUp";
import { scale, vs } from "react-native-size-matters";
import { createDrawerNavigator } from "@react-navigation/drawer";
import { createMaterialBottomTabNavigator } from "@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs";
import { Icon } from "react-native-elements";
import UserContext, { UserProvider } from "./src/screens/Context/UserContext";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";

const Tab = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator();
const Stack = createStackNavigator();
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

const signedIn = true; //this is for testing
const drawer_style = {
  backgroundColor: "#202B35",
  activeTintColor: "#000",

  width: 200,
};

const drawer_item_style = {
  activeTintColor: "orange",
  inactiveTintColor: "#fff",

  itemStyle: { marginVertical: vs(10) },
};

const non_user_stack = () => {
  <Stack.Navigator>
    <Stack.Screen
      name="Sign in - Cal "
      component={LoginScreen}
      options={({ navigation }) => ({
        headerShown: true,
        headerTintColor: "orange",

        headerStyle: {
          backgroundColor: "#202B35",
        },
      })}
    />

    <Stack.Screen
      name="Sign up - Cal "
      component={SignUpScreen}
      options={({ navigation }) => ({
        headerShown: true,
        headerTintColor: "orange",

        headerStyle: {
          backgroundColor: "#202B35",
        },
      })}
    />
  </Stack.Navigator>;
};

const UserMenu = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Drawer.Navigator
        initialRouteName="Home"
        drawerStyle={drawer_style}
        drawerContentOptions={drawer_item_style}
        drawerType="front"
      >
        <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={MyStack} />
      </Drawer.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};
const MyStack = () => {

  return(

    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Cal"
        component={BottomNav}
        options={({ navigation }) => ({
          headerShown: true,
          headerTintColor: "orange",

          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: "#202B35",
          },
          headerLeft: (props) => (
            <Icon
              size={25}
              name={"ios-menu"}
              iconStyle={{
                fontSize: scale(30),
                color: "orange",
                margin: 5,
                marginLeft: 10,
              }}
              type="ionicon"
              color="orange"
              onPress={() => {
                navigation.toggleDrawer();
              }}
            />
          ),
        })}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  ) 
};


export default App = () => {

  const { isSignedIn, check_and_set_signin_status } = useContext(UserContext); //<-- causes crash

  return (
      isSignedIn === "false" ? (
       <UserProvider>
         <UserMenu />
       </UserProvider>
    ) : (
      <non_user_stack></non_user_stack>
    );
  );

};
```

**UserContext.js :**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import * as Permissions from "expo-permissions";
import axios from "axios";
import { AsyncStorage } from "react-native";
//import registerForPushNotificationsAsync from "../Hooks/registerForPushNotifications";
import Constants from "expo-constants";

const UserContext = React.createContext();

const IS_SIGNEDIN = "is_signed_in";

export const UserProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [isSignedIn, setSignIn] = useState(null);
  const [didAuthenticate, setAuthenticated] = useState(null);

  //Check if this user already signed in before and didnt log out since their last session
  //used for conditional rendering
  const check_and_set_signin_status = async () => {
    const signed_in = await AsyncStorage.getItem(IS_SIGNEDIN);

    if (signed_in == null || signed_in == "false") {
      await AsyncStorage.setItem(IS_SIGNEDIN, "false");
      setSignIn("false");
    } else {
      setSignIn("true");
    }

  };


  return (
    <UserContext.Provider
      value={{
        isSignedIn, // well use this for conditional rendering

        check_and_set_signin_status,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </UserContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

**The Error :**

[image]

Comment: what version of react do you use

Comment: react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.61.4

Comment: did you resolve your problem from my answer?

Comment: you pointed out some minor mistakes but still threw same error.

Comment: I think you accept my answer first now you have removed accepted answer.

Comment: I fixed it myself, but couldn't get it done without your pointers. thank you sir, bounty should be deposited into your account :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

there is some mistake in your code

1. you are not exporting `UserContext` but you are importing UserContext
   in App.js file
2. you are trying to use useContext and provider in same file but you
   have to `useContext` inside of Provider child component
3. you are non_user_stack with first letter capital but you have to
   make first letter capital

**UserContext.js :** you have to export UserContext in this file

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Text } from 'react-native'
import * as Permissions from "expo-permissions";
import axios from "axios";
import { AsyncStorage } from "react-native";
//import registerForPushNotificationsAsync from "../Hooks/registerForPushNotifications";
import Constants from "expo-constants";

const UserContext = React.createContext();
export default UserContext;
const IS_SIGNEDIN = "is_signed_in";

export const UserProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [isSignedIn, setSignIn] = useState(null);
  const [didAuthenticate, setAuthenticated] = useState(null);
  const check_and_set_signin_status = async () => {
    const signed_in = await AsyncStorage.getItem(IS_SIGNEDIN);

    if (signed_in == null || signed_in == "false") {
      await AsyncStorage.setItem(IS_SIGNEDIN, "false");
      setSignIn("false");
    } else {
      setSignIn("true");
    }

  };


  return (
    <UserContext.Provider
      value={{
        isSignedIn, // well use this for conditional rendering

        check_and_set_signin_status,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </UserContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

**App.js Code :**

```
const App = () => {
 const { isSignedIn, check_and_set_signin_status } = useContext(UserContext); //<-- causes crash
  console.log( isSignedIn, check_and_set_signin_status ,"useContext")
  return isSignedIn === "false" ? (
    <UserMenu />
  ) : (
    <Non_user_stack></Non_user_stack>
  );
};

const jsx = () => (
  <UserProvider>
    <App />
  </UserProvider>
);

export default jsx;
```

Comment: Dear Muhammad, I get the same error without any of the above problems I export both context and provider consts, I hope You be able to check my code
```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export const LanguageContext = React.createContext();

export const LanguageProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [language, setLanguage] = useState("en");

  return (
    <LanguageContext.Provider value={{ language, setLanguage }}>
      {children}
    </LanguageContext.Provider>
  );
};

```

Answer (score 9):

In my case I imported badly

```
import ThemeContext from '../contexts/theme-context';
```

Instead

```
import { ThemeContext } from '../contexts/theme-context';
```

Answer (score 1):

You should always check what you're exporting from your context folder

In my case I `import { LocalContext } from ".././services/location/location.context";`

instead of `import { LocationContext } from ".././services/location/location.context";`

Answer (score 1):

Mine was:
I mistakenly imported the file (languageContext.js) instead of its function {LanguageContext} so now it goes like this where I called my context.

```
 import {LanguageContext} from "../../Context/languageContext";

 const { language } = useContext(languageContext);
 i18n.locale = language;
```